# Trying to identify why wordpress adds "test-post" to URL of any new pages I create

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a site using the Horizon theme on wordpress. Permalinks set to /%postname%/.

But every time I create a new page, once I press publish the page refreshes with /test-post/ added to the permalink. e.g. mysite.com/test-post/mypage/
I have no idea where this test-post is being added from.

I have Yeost SEO plugin running, iThemes Security also.

I've checked .htaccess, and wondering what other wp files might be able to alter the path?

Comment: It's like your post are subpages of */test-post/* and it seams like a theme problem. I think that the support team of your premium theme *Horizon* could better help you, [opening a support ticket](https://zorbix.ticksy.com). Have you check in the additional settings coming within your theme? This additional settings can be on pages and post too…

Comment: Yes I think so. It may even be a WP issue, it happens when I make it a chiled of the Home Page. So I'm now looking to see if the home page has some setting to make the permalink say test-post